# Upgrade to PHP7.3 and Changing Apache from Prefork to Event Breaks WordPress

Tags: php, server, apache

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

I just updated my server from PHP7.2 to PHP7.3 [using this guide](https://ayesh.me/Ubuntu-PHP-7.3)

After that, I changed my Apache from Prefork to Event [using this guide](https://serverfault.com/a/904115/386035)

Now, when going to my Wordpress website, I see the following instead of a normal home page:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Furthermore, now all the different pages and posts display a similar output (i.e. code is being displayed instead of an actual page)

Is this a known bug of PHP7.3 or have I done anything wrong?

Any help and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen this but it doesn't look to be a WP problem but an Apache/PHP problem. TBH you're probably better off asking on ServerFault. I expect the classic PHP file with just `<?php phpinfo();` would be enough of a test case on its own, get that working first before trying a full CMS

Comment: It's related to server configuration for sure. Can you check if PHP is installed and running?
This could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: @Kumar, @TomJNowell, when I tested my server with `<?php phpinfo();`, The page would just display the code instead of outputting the actual PHP output. This was because PHP was disabled and the PHP-FPM module was not active. I've now managed to fix it by doing a `sudo a2enconf php7.3-fpm` and restarting both Apache and PHP FPM.

Answer (score 0):

I've now managed to fix this issue and managed to successfully migrate form Prefork to Event.

For some reason Apache didn't let me `sudo a2enmod php7.3`

I entered `sudo a2enconf php7.3-fpm` instead of the `a2enmod` command above, I then restarted both Apache and the PHP FPM service with `sudo service apache2 restart && sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

After it had restarted, going back to the Wordpress website revealed that the server is now able to read PHP code and display a normal Wordpress website.